# Angular JS : How to focus on drop-down when the other drop-down option is selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, focus

I am having 2 drop-downs.
I want values for both the drop-downs together and for that if I select value from 1 drop-down, I want to make focus on 2nd drop-down to tell user that they need to select 2nd drop-down value to complete the process

```
    // vm-tags.directive
div.acp-rd__search__tags
    .row
        .col-md-6
            ui-select(
                ng-model="viewmodel.filters.TagName"
                on-select="FilterController.on.uiSelectChange($item, $model, 'TagName')"
                ng-disabled="bindingIncomplete"
            )
                ui-select-match(
                    allow-clear="true"
                    placeholder="Tag name..."
                )
                    | {{$select.selected.name}}
                ui-select-choices(
                    repeat="tag in IndexController.data.tags.index | filter: $select.search"
                )
                    | {{tag.name|| '&nbsp;'}}
        .col-md-6
            ui-select(
                ng-model="viewmodel.filters.TagValue"
                ng-disabled="!viewmodel.filters.TagName"
                on-select="FilterController.on.uiSelectChange($item, $model, 'TagValue')"
            )
                ui-select-match(
                    allow-clear="true"
                    placeholder="Tag value..."
                )
                    | {{$select.selected}}
                ui-select-choices(
                    repeat="value in viewmodel.filters.TagName.TagValues | filter: $select.search | orderBy"
                )
                    span(ng-if="value") {{ value }}
                    span(ng-if="!value")
                        em blank
// / vm-tags.directive
```

Comment: That will likely create an unfriendly UI. If the user is navigating options with the cursor keys, how do you know when to shift focus to the other select?

Comment: Have you tried adding ng-change?